# programmatically scroll to a specific page/position with autolayout iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am using autolayout with a scroll view.  It is working great, but I need to be able to scroll to specific pages programmatically.  Specifically, I need to scroll to the last page after the view loads.  How do I do this?  My scrolling essentially has the visual format shown below, except the number of pages is dynamic.

```
visual format for vertically scrolling (swap V and H for horizontally scrolling):

view hierarchy is scrollContainer(UIView) -> scrollView(UIScrollView) -> contentView(UIView) -> pages(UIView’s)

V:|scrollView|
H:|scrollView|

V:|contentView|
H:|contentView|

V:|[page1(==scrollContainer)][page2(==scrollContainer)][page3(==scrollContainer)]|
H:|[page1(==scrollContainer)]|
H:|[page2(==scrollContainer)]|
H:|[page3(==scrollContainer)]|
```

**edit: clarifying my question**

The code to offset the scrollview is below.  But when can I get the origin of the page I want to scroll to using autolayout?  If I put it in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it updates every time the device is rotated.  I need to update just when the view is loaded.  Is there a more appropriate method to override? Or is there a way of setting the origin with a constraint?

```
    let lastPage = pages?.last
    if lastPage != nil {
        let origin = lastPage!.frame.origin
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(origin, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a horizontal scroll view:

```
CGPoint lastPage = CGPointMake((numberOfPages - 1) * pageWidth, 0.0f);
```

If vertical:

```
CGPoint lastPage = CGPointMake(0.0f, (numberOfPages - 1) * pageHeight);
```

Then just use the scroll view's method:

```
 [scrollView setContentOffset:lastPage animated:YES];
```

---

You can leave this code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, just add an if-statement to test if it's the first time or not:

```
if (!self.alreadyScrolled) {
    [self scrollToDesiredPage];
    self.alreadyScrolled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about setContentOffset.  I'm still looking for when to call the method.  I need it to call once after everything loads and pageWidth/pageHeight is loaded

Comment: `I need to update just when the view is loaded.` Have you tried `viewDidLoad` maybe?

Comment: viewDidLoad is too early to get the frames, but I've got it figured out.  I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
CGPoint desiredOffset = CGPointMake(0.0,desiredPageNumber * pageHeight);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:desiredOffset animated:YES];
```

Obviously tweak it as you need to. I don't believe you can or should achieve this by animating constraints, because of the unique way autolayout treats scroll views.